# Multiply textures in Android OpenGL ES 1.1

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

I'm trying to learn OpenGL on Android and as part of my learning project I want to make part of a texture transparent.  To accomplish that I've got a texture that's all white with the alpha channel set to transparent where I want the transparency.  My plan was to multiply this against the texture I want to display, but I'm a little boggled by the abbreviated function names and integer constants.

Any simple but complete examples with texture multiplication out there?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: my bad, I just saw that you're looking for an gl 1.0 example

Looks like you're looking for a multi-texture example: http://code.google.com/p/opengles-book-samples/source/browse/trunk/Android/Ch10_MultiTexture/src/com/openglesbook/multitexture/MultiTextureRenderer.java?r=45

It's an opengl es 2.0 example. When you read the code, you'll see that the actual blending of the texture is done is in the fragmentshader.

EDIT 2 : I couldn't find a opengl-es 1.1 example, but I have some old opengl 2.0 code lying around. It's in c/c++, so you'll have to convert it to java yourself.

I looked up the GLES 1.1 spec, and it seems it supports the key functions from my code: glActiveTexture, glMultiTexCoord and glTexEnvi, so this may help get you started...

```
glActiveTextureARB( GL_TEXTURE0_ARB );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, KdMapIndex );
glTexEnvi( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);

glActiveTextureARB( GL_TEXTURE1_ARB );
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, KaMapIndex);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_ADD);

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
for (face = faces.begin(); face != faces.end(); face++)
{
    CVector3f normal;
    CVector2f texture0, texture1, texture2;
    CVector3f vertex0, vertex1, vertex2;

    normal.x = data.normals[face->nIndex[0]-1].x;
    normal.y = data.normals[face->nIndex[1]-1].y;
    normal.z = data.normals[face->nIndex[2]-1].z;
    normal.normalize();

    texture0 = data.texcoords[face->tIndex[0]-1];
    texture1 = data.texcoords[face->tIndex[1]-1];
    texture2 = data.texcoords[face->tIndex[2]-1];

    vertex0 = data.vertices[face->vIndex[0]-1];
    vertex1 = data.vertices[face->vIndex[1]-1];
    vertex2 = data.vertices[face->vIndex[2]-1];

    glNormal3f(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);       // Face normal

    glMultiTexCoord2fARB( GL_TEXTURE0_ARB, texture0.x, texture0.y ); // texcoord 0
    glMultiTexCoord2fARB( GL_TEXTURE1_ARB, texture0.x, texture0.y );        
    glVertex3f(vertex0.x, vertex0.y, vertex0.z);    // vertex 0

    glMultiTexCoord2fARB( GL_TEXTURE0_ARB, texture1.x, texture1.y ); // texcoord 1
    glMultiTexCoord2fARB( GL_TEXTURE1_ARB, texture1.x, texture1.y );    
    glVertex3f(vertex1.x, vertex1.y, vertex1.z);    // vertex 1

    glMultiTexCoord2fARB( GL_TEXTURE0_ARB, texture2.x, texture2.y ); // texcoord 2
    glMultiTexCoord2fARB( GL_TEXTURE1_ARB, texture2.x, texture2.y );    
    glVertex3f(vertex2.x, vertex2.y, vertex2.z);    // vertex 2
}
glEnd();
```

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I'm using a library that requires ES 1.0

Comment: Minor scratch that: ES 1.1.  Still not 2.0 though

Comment: Like I said, I'm learning so I'ma pepper you with questions.  Feel free to answer these or not, as they're ancillary.  Are glBegin() and glEnd() necessary?  I'm not dealing with face normals (this is all flat with no dynamic lighting) and my vertices are all bundled into a single float[] buffer

Comment: No, glBegin() and glEnd() are not necessary. Like I said, this is old code and this particular sample was pulled out of a displaylist. What's most relevant here are the glMultiTexCoord calls and the glTexEnv calls that determine the blending of the textures. You can ignore the rest, but I think the general principles here could apply to opengl-es as well (mind you, that is assumption on my part).